# Mocha/Chai - test specific setup and tear down

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I know mocha has global before and after, and each-test before and after, but what I would like is test-specific before and after. Something like SoapUI has.

For example, say that I have a test checking that the creation of a user works.

I want to remove the user, should it exist, from the database BEFORE the test. And I want the test to ensure that the user is removed AFTER the test. But I do not want to do this for EACH test, as only one test will actually create the user. Other tests will delete user/s, update user/s, fail to create an already existing user etc.

Is this possible, or do I have to include the setup and tear down code in the test? If so, how do I ensure that both the setup and tear down executes properly, independent of the test result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For tests where I need to have special setup and teardown code but that are not otherwise distinguishable from their siblings, I just put a `describe` block with an empty title:

```
describe("SomeClass", () => {
    describe("#someMethod", () => {
        it("does something", () => {});
        it("does something else", () => {});

        describe("", () => {
            // The before and after hooks apply only to the tests in
            // this block.
            before(() => {});
            after(() => {});

            it("does something more", () => {});
        });
    });
});
```

> Is this possible, or do I have to include the setup and tear down code in the test? If so, how do I ensure that both the setup and tear down executes properly, independent of the test result?

You *can* put setup and tear down code in the test itself (i.e. inside an the callback you pass to `it`). However, Mocha will treat *any* failure there as a failed *test*, period. It does not matter where in the callback passed to `it` the failure occurs. Assertion libraries allow you to provide custom error messages which can help you figure out what exactly failed, but Mocha will see all failures in `it` the same way: the test failed. If you want Mocha to treat failures in setup/teardown code differently from test failures, then you *have* to use the hooks as I've shown above.

Comment: Thanks, then I know. So, while a little roundabout, it is good to know that there is a way to handle the setup and teardown.